# ToExpression in nested Set/SetDelayed

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, assignment

Suppose we have the following definitions.

```
SetAttributes[AllValues, HoldAll];
AllValues[s_] := Map[#[s] &, {OwnValues, DownValues, SubValues, UpValues}]

setx1[x_] := x1 = x
setx2[x_] := x2 := x
setx3[x_] := x3 = ToExpression["x"]
setx4[x_] := x4 := ToExpression["x"]
```

and evaluate

```
setx1[1];
setx2[2];
setx3[3];
setx4[4];
```

This yields the following "bindings".

```
AllValues[setx1]
{{}, {HoldPattern[setx1[x_]] :> (x1 = x)}, {}, {}}

AllValues[x1]
{{HoldPattern[x1] :> 1}, {}, {}, {}}

AllValues[setx2]
{{}, {HoldPattern[setx2[x_]] :> (x2 := x)}, {}, {}}

AllValues[x2]
{{HoldPattern[x2] :> 2}, {}, {}, {}}

AllValues[setx3]
{{}, {HoldPattern[setx3[x_]] :> (x3 = ToExpression["x"])}, {}, {}}

AllValues[x3]
{{HoldPattern[x3] :> x}, {}, {}, {}}

AllValues[setx4]
{{}, {HoldPattern[setx4[x_]] :> (x4 := ToExpression["x"])}, {}, {}}

AllValues[x4]
{{HoldPattern[x4] :> ToExpression["x"]}, {}, {}, {}}
```

Clearly, `ToExpression["x"]` does not refer to the value bound by the pattern `x_`. How can such a "binding" be established without explicitly using the pattern variable? Note that replacing `ToExpression` by `Evaluate@ToExpression` does not work because the right hand side of `setx*` is not evaluated when evaluating the definitions.

Comment: tl;dr: If I set `f[x_]:=ToExpression["x"]` and I call `f[51]` then I get `x` and not `51`. What can I do about it? (I think you need to explain why you insist on using `ToExpression` and why you cannot simply use `x` on the right hand side.)

Comment: One use case is metaprogramming. Of course you can argue that when the definition is evaluated, there should be `x` literally on the rhs. I am just wondering whether there are other techniques that can be used.

Comment: `x` in `ToExpression["x"]` is always a string, not an expression or variable.  If `x `is already an expression, why do you want to use `ToExpression`?

Comment: I have yet to see an application of `ToExpression` that makes sense. Usually `ToExpression` is a strong indicator of [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but maybe `Unevaluated` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Roman - that sounds a bit extreme.  I'm sure you could write a file parser that avoids `ToExpression` altogether, but I don't see why you would.